# Integral of a gradient over a plane area

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $A$ be a plane area bounded by a curve $\partial A$. Then, is

$$ \iint_A \nabla f\, \textrm{d}x \textrm{d}y = \oint_{\partial A} f\ \hat{\mathbf{n}}\ dl $$

where $f=f(x,y)$ and $\mathbf{\hat n}$ is the outward unit normal?

Comment: Bye_World  - thanks

Comment: @user89699 What is to be done here ?

Answer (score 4):

Under the assumptions for the Divergence Theorem to apply, we have

$$\iint_A \nabla \cdot \vec F\,dx\,dy=\oint_{\partial A} \vec F\cdot \hat n\, d\ell$$

Now, let $\vec F=\hat x_i f$.  Then, we have

$$\iint_A \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\,dx\,dy=\oint_{\partial A}f\,(\hat x_i\cdot \hat n)\,d\ell \tag 1$$

Multiplying $(1)$ by $\hat x_i$ and summing over $i$ from $i=1$ to $i=2$ yields

> $$\iint_A \nabla f\,dA=\oint_{\partial A} f\,\hat n\,d\ell$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: I dont think this is right - If $\vec F=\hat x_i f $, then

Comment: $$ \nabla \cdot \vec F = 2f + \vec x \cdot \nabla f $$

Comment: @user89699 $\hat x_i$ denotes a unit vector, not a coordinate variable.  So, the answer is correct.  Anf $f$ is a scalar, not a vector.

Comment: +1. This identity is useful to derive Archimedes Principle ( Eureka !!! ).

Comment: @FelixMarin Thank you Felix!

Comment: Dr.MV - this is still  not correct. If $ \hat x_i $ are unit vectors, then $$ \nabla \cdot \vec F =  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}\ + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}\ $$ From there, I do not see how you can get to the final result.

Comment: @user89699 No, it is correct.  $\hat x_i$ is a Cartesian Unit vector and does not depend on the coordinate variables.  So, $$\nabla \cdot (\hat x_i f)=f\,\,\overbrace{\nabla \cdot (\hat x_i)}^{=0}+\overbrace{(\hat x_i \cdot \nabla )}^{=\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}}f=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$$